# Telerik Radcalender inside Repeater - Events not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

I am using Telerik Rad controls in my project. I have a RadCalendar inside a Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultRpt" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<telerik:RadCalendar Style="width: 191px; height: 123px" ID="RadCalendar1" runat="server"
EnableMonthYearFastNavigation="false" AutoPostBack="true" MultiViewColumns="1"
MultiViewRows="1" EnableMultiSelect="true">
</telerik:RadCalendar>
<telerik:RadToolTipManager Width="270px" Height="135px" Style="font-size: 11px" RelativeTo="Element"
ID="RadToolTipManager1" runat="server" OffsetX="7" Position="MiddleRight" OnAjaxUpdate="RadToolTipmanager1_AjaxUpdate" Skin="Telerik" AutoCloseDelay="90000" </telerik:RadToolTipManager>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

this is my RadAjaxManager

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
<AjaxSettings>
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadCalendar1">
<UpdatedControls>
<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadCalendar1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
</telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
</UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
<telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="calMarker">
<UpdatedControls>
<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadCalendar1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
</telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
<telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="calMarker" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
</telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
</UpdatedControls>
</telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
<ClientEvents OnRequestStart="RequestStart" OnResponseEnd="ResponseEnd" />
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="WebBlue" />
```

The tool tip on the date is not working. And the loading panel is not working for the onclick on the RadCalendar (instead the page is postbacking).

The calmarker control is a panel bar which is also inside the repeater its loading panel is also not working.

These was working when there was no repeater. After i put the repeater control the issue started.

Regards
Sankardeep

Answer (score 0):

Report that directly to telerik, either in forum post or a support ticket. Their support folks are quite helpful and can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Listview instead of a Repeater and see if that helps.